# form using validation include onsubmit= action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to ask first if the form is filled out correctly?  OK or Cancel and then submit the form over action to other page.

This is how it works without validate it first:

```
<form method="POST" id="test" onSubmit= action="./test.html">
```

This is what i tried but is not working: 
Is the form filled out correctly?

```
<form method="POST" id="test" onSubmit="if(copy('Is the form filled out correctly?')){return false;}" action="./test.html">
```

Many thanks for your help and support

Comment: You must use "confirm" instead of "copy" to ask for user confirmation

Comment: thank you, but if i click "cancel" the form will be submitted. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, referer to this solution:

```
var form = document.querySelector("#test");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return confirm("Is the form filled out correctly?"));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="test" action="./test.html">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

JS:

```
const form = document.querySelector("#test");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  if (!confirm("Is the form filled out correctly?")) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but if i click "cancel" the form will be submitted instead to return